# how to pass both queryStrings and JSON Body using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
 return try Alamofire.URLEncoding.queryString.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
```

How should I pass JSON body too as parameters.

Answer (score -1):

Alamofire.request(url,
                              method: .post,
                              parameters: parameters,
                              encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                              headers: [:])

```
            .responseJSON { response in
```

//continue...
//parameters must be valid [String: AnyObject]